# Cannot listen to remote beanstalkd message queue

Tags: beanstalkd

I have a remote server (Ubuntu 16.04), with beanstalkd installed. I have successfully started the message queue with the following command:

```
beanstalkd -l 123.123.123.123 -p 11300 &
```

On my localhost, I have installed beanstalkd and am trying to connect to the remote queue with the command:

```
beanstalkd -l 123.123.123.123 -p 11300 &
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
beanstalkd: net.c:119 in make_server_socket: bind(): Can't assign requested address
beanstalkd: main.c:64 in main: make_server_socket()
```

How can I connect to a remote beanstalkd message queue?

Comment: You are trying to connect to a beanstalkd server, from another beanstalkd server, on a different box? Use a client to connect to the server, and don't try to listen on an IP that is not on the machine. You can connect to that IP address, but you can't listen to it from elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You are issuing the same CONNECT command again, and as it was already started the error message means you cannot use the same port for listen again.

As regarding how you can connect to beanstalkd you should use a [web UI](https://github.com/ptrofimov/beanstalk_console) for that, and not a telnet script as the protocol is very chatty and you probably are after a UI/library thing that you can use from inside of your application.